# how to upload a certain file extension

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In html, I use this code

```
<form action="upload.html">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

to filter image files that will be chosen, how to implements it in thymeleaf?

Comment: To clarify to all, are you saying that when the file select box pops up you want it only to show image files (png, jpg etc.) and not all files (*.*)?

Comment: thanks all, this my code :
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" class="form-control" />

and this code is work, my mistake is :
 <form action="upload.html" accept="image/*" >